# SQL code to change value of a field on one table based on value of a different field in a different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a complete novice at SQL so please be gentle...

I have a database of products. I would like to use SQL to move a batch of products to a different category, based on if a particular word is present in the products title, and also, only if the products quantity is zero.

The database includes 2 relevant tables:

- 1st table is `products` which has these 2 relevant columns: `products_quantity` and `master_categories_id`
- 2nd table is `products_description` and it has relevant column `products_name` (the title)

So, for an example, a product with the following title (stored in the column `products name`):

```
Archimede Seguso Murano Incalmo Millefiori Glass Bowl
```

I would like the SQL code to find this product (any any others that contain the word `Archimede` in the title), check if the stock quantity is `0`, and if so, change the value of the column `master_categories_id` to `277` for those products.

The code I have so far come up with is:

```
UPDATE products
SET master_categories_id = '277'
WHERE products_quantity = '0' and products_name = 'Archimede';
```

However, this does not work as the column `products_name` is not in the `products` table.  I have spent many hours searching for the correct method of doing this, with no luck, and would be eternally grateful for any help!

My website is built using zencart, and the above SQL was run using Zen Carts Admin "SQL Query Executor", but I can also run the SQL using phpMyAdmin if that helps.  I am using MySQL version 5.

Sorry if I have left out anything obvious that you need to know, like I said I am a complete novice, but I will try to provide any other info you need.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: There should be some common filed which relates the products in  one table to the another table. You can't move forward without that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a products id column in both tables that you can use to JOIN, you will need to JOIN the tables to do the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE products p
INNER JOIN products_description pd
  on p.product_id = pd.product_id
SET p.master_categories_id = '277'
WHERE p.products_quantity = '0' 
  and pd.products_name = 'Archimede';
```

If you want to update any rows that contain `Archimede`, then you will have to use the `LIKE` operator in SQL:

```
UPDATE products p
INNER JOIN products_description pd
  on p.product_id = pd.product_id
SET p.master_categories_id = '277'
WHERE p.products_quantity = '0' 
  and pd.products_name LIKE '%Archimede%';
```

The `LIKE` operator will find any rows that contain `Archimede` in the title.

Comment: Definitely on the right track (had to change "product_id" to "products_id") but it's now apparent that there is a 3rd table which also needs changing:

table name: "products_to_categories".
2 fields: "products_id" and "categories_id".

The "categories_id" field in that table will also need changing to the same number (eg 277) as the "master_categories_id".  Sorry for not realising this earlier, and thanks very much for help so far!

Comment: @WayneStephens So is the category id that needs to be changed in a different table?

Comment: Yes, a third table named "products_to_categories".  I don't know how to join 3 tables (before your help I didn't know how to join 2 tables) but I've got around it for now by running the following script after the first script:

`UPDATE products_to_categories pc
INNER JOIN products p
  on pc.products_id = p.products_id
SET pc.categories_id = '277'
WHERE p.master_categories_id = '277';`